# md-datepicker still $dirty when typing the date

Tags: datepicker, angular-material2

I would like to know why the md-datepicker  style dirty when typing the the date and note choosing from the calender

```
  <md-form-field>
    <input mdInput [mdDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="{{ ('ma.date.de.naissance') | translate }}"
            name="dateNaissance" [(ngModel)]="dateNaissance" data-error="Date de naissance de client invalid" required>
    <md-datepicker-toggle mdSuffix [for]="picker"></md-datepicker-toggle>
    <md-datepicker #picker></md-datepicker>
  </md-form-field>
```

Comment: I set the locale lang at fr this._dateAdapter.setLocale('fr');

Answer (score 0):

Dirty means the input has been modified from its original value. As soon as you start typing, `dirty` will be set true.

Touched means the input has been focused and then blurred. It will be set as soon as the user clicks into the input and then moves focus elsewhere.